# Using window.opener in IE11

Tags: javascript, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, window.open, window.opener

I have a little problem at my work.

Here is my code.

- parent window

  ```
  child = window.open(url, "pop", "width=790,height=890,scrollbars=yes");

  $("#module").attr("action", "https://~~~").attr("async", false).attr("method", "GET").attr("target", "pop").attr("acceptCharset", "UTF-8").submit().focus();
  ```
- child window

  ```
  $(opener.location).attr("href", "javascript:functionName();");
  open(location, "_self").close();
  ```

These codes are error free in all browsers and OS.

There is a problem with one particular laptop.

The problem is 'missing  opener'.

This error run on IE11, Windows10 on particular laptop.

It run well on another browser in same laptop.

Comment: Edge browser works?

Comment: Yes, no problem on Edge.

Comment: "`$(opener.location).attr("href", "javascript:...`" are you serious?!?

Comment: Just by chance did you clear you IE cache and saved data also resetting setting to default

Comment: #Aluan 
Yes, I refer to this site.
https://www.sitefinity.com/developer-resources/forums/developing-with-sitefinity-/jquery-location-attr-href-url-not-working-as-desired

Answer (score 0):

Your IE is most likely running in protected mode. This is a known issue/feature: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/5d9efaa1-78d5-45dc-a04d-d9fde768379f/ie-11-windowopener-in-popup-dialog.

> "The window.opener property is nulled in a particular scenario when Protected Mode / UAC are enabled for the content in question."

Try turning it off and seeing if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

**IE blocks popups for real!**

If the browser settings are set to block all popups, your window.open method will return null; and therefore your *opener* will also be invalid.

Try CTRL and/or CTRL+ALT to override the blocker while invoking the popup.
Or change the settings on the given laptop.